# How to Implement Dynamic Dependent Dropdown Using Laravel and inertia js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

From the topic name, my question is how do I make a child drop-down list, for example, I have a table of sub-sections linked to the table of departments. I want when I click on the name of the department it shows its sub-sections via laravel + inertia js with vue3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have implemented one-to-many relation between Department and SubSection(Ex: Department has many subsections).

So you have a Department model with the relation below

```
public function subsections()
{
   return $this->hasMany(SubSection::class, 'department_id');
}
```

Make an endpoint to fetch all the subsections against a department.

```
// something like this
Route::get('/subsections', function(Department $department) {
  return response()->json([
     'sub_sections' => $department->subsections
  ]);
});
```

Then in the vue form make two dropdowns. One to show the department list and another to load the subsections against that selected department. Add a @change event on the department dropdown and fire a method to fetch data through API and fill out that in the subsections dropdown.

Your vue component may have something like this:

```
data() {
   return {
     subsections: []
   }
},

methods: {
  loadSubsection(departmentId)
  {
     axios.get('/subsections')
        .then(response => this.subsections = response.data. sub_sections)
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
   }
}
```

Comment: Any idea way we can't use Inertia.get() instead of axios ?

Comment: If I am not wrong Inertia::get() do something else. At least from the docs.

https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits#browser-history